# Create SQL Job for each row inserted in Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in SQl which does contain token as varchar. Every token has set the validity value in integer (mins) for example 60 for 1 hr, 120 for 2 hours. Also there is a timestamp

```
________________________________________
token  | validity  |  timestamp
________________________________________
22EFR  | 60        | 23-02-2018 16:00
23EFR  | 120       | 23-02-2018 13:00
________________________________________
```

I wanted SQL to run job so that if the token is expired as per the validity and timestamp the row should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE a sql job that execute the following SQL - set the frequency of the job to whatever suits your needs

```
DELETE
FROM table
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, Validitiy, Timestamp) < GETDATE()
```